# Validation on SpringBoot API method does not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, spring-annotations

There's a `createCar` API below with a `createCarVO` as its request body. Usually, there's a `@Validated` annotation in front of the `createCarVO` parameter in the controller method. However, in my example below, the `@Validated` and the annotation are deferred to service layer, i.e. deferred to CarServiceImpl.createCar(). The validation is expected to work in CarServiceImpl.createCar(), but actually it doesn't.

```
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class CarApiController {

    ...

    @PostMapping(value = "/cars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CarVO createCar(@RequestBody CreateCarVO createCarVO) {
        CreateCarVO templateCarVO = templateService.prepareCarByTemplateId(createCarVO.getTemplateId());
        templateService.overwriteTemplate(createCarVO, templateCarVO);

        // Validation on templateCarVO is deferred from controller to CarServiceImpl
        return carService.createCar(templateCarVO);
    }
}
```

```
public interface ICarService {
    CarVO createCar(@Validated CreateCarVO createCarVO);
}
```

```
@Validated
@Component
public class CarServiceImpl implements ICarService {

    ...

    /*
     * Validation on createCarVO's attributes is expected to take effect.
     * However, it doesn't validate any attribute of createCarVO at all.
     */
    @Override
    public CarVO createCar(@Validated CreateCarVO createCarVO) {
        ...
    }
}
```

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CreateCarVO {

    public String templateId;

    @NotEmpty(message = "name cannot be empty")
    @Length(max = 64, message = "Max length of name is 64")
    public String name;

    @Length(max = 64, message = "Max length of producer is 64")
    private String producer;

    ...
    
    // Setters & Getters
}
```

Usually, if call the `createCar` API without a `name`, error like below is expected. However, in this example, there's none.

```
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [createCarVO.name,name]; arguments []; default message [title]]; default message [name cannot be empty]] 
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134) ~[spring-web-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) [spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) [spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) [spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) [javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
```

So, if I insist on deferring the validation on `CreateCarVO` from controller to CarServiceImpl.createCar(), what shall I do? If there's no way to do it that way, is there any alternative solution?

Comment: Did you try by putting `@Valid` next to `@RequestBody` in controller?

Comment: If put `@Valid` next to `@RequestBody` in the controller, the validation will not be deferred to carService.createCar(templateCarVO). What I expect is that the controller will not do the validation, but deferred to carService.createCar(templateCarVO).

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Valid like this and its simpler than others,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class CarApiController {

    ...

    @PostMapping(value = "/cars", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public CarVO createCar(@RequestBody @Valid CreateCarVO createCarVO) {
        CreateCarVO templateCarVO = templateService.prepareCarByTemplateId(createCarVO.getTemplateId());
        templateService.overwriteTemplate(createCarVO, templateCarVO);

        // Validation on templateCarVO is deferred from controller to CarServiceImpl
        return carService.createCar(templateCarVO);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I hope to defer the validation from controller (CarApiController.createCar()) to carService.createCar(templateCarVO).

If add @Valid in CarApiController.createCar(), the validation is not deferred. So, I'm wondering how can I defer the validation to carService.createCar(templateCarVO).